# enumeration yielded no results Error in EF ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.Net MVC3 Razor project i have to implement customer registration.When saving data it returns the error that

> "enumeration yielded no results"

.What is this error mean? and How to solve this?

Controller Code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CustomerRegistration(CustomerViewModel cusmodel)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

               if (cusmodel.CarrerPlanning)
                sb.Append("Career Planning");
            if (cusmodel.Personal)
                sb.Append("Personal");
            if (cusmodel.Relationship)
                sb.Append("Parenting");
            if (cusmodel.ActivityPlan)
                sb.Append("Activity Plan for Childern");
            if (cusmodel.Stress)
                sb.Append("Stress Management");
            cusmodel.Purpose = sb.ToString();

            try
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    cus.CusModelData.Add(cusmodel);
                    cus.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("ShowSuccess", "Home");

                }
                return View();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.Message.ToString());
            }




        }
```

Customer View Model

```
 public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int CusId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Age is required")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Age ")]
        public int age { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string FathName { get; set; }
        public string MothName { get; set; }
        public string OrgSchooName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PIN { get; set; }
        public string tele { get; set; }
        public string Mob { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Web { get; set; }
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
        public string brief { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }


        public bool CarrerPlanning { get; set; }
        public bool Personal { get; set; }
        public bool Relationship { get; set; }
        public bool Parenting { get; set; }
        public bool ActivityPlan { get; set; }
        public bool Stress { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        //public IList<CustomerViewModel> CheckBoxItems { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<string> CheckBoxItemsValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does this happen? I guess `var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);`?

Comment: @HenkMollema    cus.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be down to the LINQ selecting from the ModelState errors. Can you wrap it in a check to make sure there are actually any values in ModelState like:

```
if(ModelState.Values.Count()>0) {
     var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

} else {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         cus.CusModelData.Add(cusmodel);
         cus.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("ShowSuccess", "Home");
     }
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Hello gough..when am using your code i can see my error that model was  null.Can you say how to solve this